# Rendering an ArrayList, sorted by its object's y position

Tags: java, arraylist, slick2d

## Solved (scroll down)

I'm currently working on a small game in Java using the game library *Slick2d*. The game itself is 2D, but you can move to the background or foreground.

### My problem

I'm currently trying to make something like a *render order*, which would be equivalent to CSS's "z-index". Otherwise, an object which is behind a player is rendered above the player.

- How to sort it
- How to render it correctly

### My code so far

```
public static List<Entity> entities;

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    entities.add(new Player(100,100, 0));

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        entities.add(new Fire(new Random().nextInt(Window.WIDTH), new Random().nextInt(Window.HEIGHT), i));
        entities.add(new Torch(new Random().nextInt(Window.WIDTH), new Random().nextInt(Window.HEIGHT), i));
        entities.add(new PassiveMob(new Random().nextInt(Window.WIDTH), new Random().nextInt(Window.HEIGHT), i));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding Entities to an ArrayList. Every Entity has a `x` and `y` position as well as a `width` and a `height` (Fire, Torch, PassiveMob and Player are instances of Entity).

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
    for(int i=0;i<entities.size();i++){
        entities.get(i).update(delta);
    }
}
```

Here I'm just updating every entity.

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    for(int i=0;i<entities.size();i++){
        entities.get(i).render(g);
    }
}
```

At the end I'm rendering every entity.

### My thoughts

- Creating a custom "renderOrder" List
- Sorting every Entity by its Y-axis and rendering it in this custom order
- Finding a method provided by Slick2D to manage this

[image: Current]

## The solution

I managed to fix it by using the following code after updating every entity:

```
    Collections.sort(entities, new Comparator<Entity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entity o1, Entity o2) {
            final int y1 = o1.y+o1.anim.getCurrentFrame().getHeight();
            final int y2 = o2.y+o2.anim.getCurrentFrame().getHeight();
            return y1 < y2 ? -1 : y1 > y2 ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
```

This sorts `ArrayList<Entity>` every tick based on the y-axis!

Comment: I do not understand why sorting by y achsis can solve hidden object drawing: x-achsis is screen from left to right. y, up/down. and z-achis is deep into the screen

Comment: @AlexWien I added a screenshot. As you can see everything is 2d based - so basically there is no z axis. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O_RDtPwKw0) is the current state. It basically just renders objects behind others when the player is "above" or "below" them.

Comment: ah the last seconds in the video showed the trick: object move on a ground plane that has an angle such that an y coordinate nearer to top of screen also means more into the background. so in your projection y and z are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first add a Z index to your `Entity` class, and make sure that the Z index of the player is either the lowest or the highest of any object in your game (depending on which way you want to sort).

Then you can just use a custom comparator that sorts by the entity's Z index and then sort your `entities` list with that comparator. Then, iterate through it like normal and render!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) is a SO question that shows you how to do the custom sorting.

Comment: You have not understood what he was aksing: You simply read his thoughts and explained how to solve hois thoughts. But his thoughts are wrong, so your answer, too.

Comment: You copied my solution.

Comment: @AlexWien The solution is obvious, and I did not even really look at your solution until I saw your comment. (Also note that I have some different things, like stating that you can sort Z in either way.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a z coordinate to each entity.
Then sort by z descending, and draw in that order. (You do this by using an Custom Comparator, I would call it `SortByZDescending`.

The z coordinate defines how far away an entity is from screen.
I would use 0 as the 2.5 d level closest to the user.
Entities on a level more distant like background graphics get higher z levels.

Comment: The asker specifically states that they want to sort on the Y-axis. (`Sorting every Entity by its Y-axis and rendering it in this custom order`)

Comment: You cannot render in that order, you have to render in the order that will not hide objects; you have to draw the most distant first. And dont downvote my answer, the asker posted his thoughts, but they are wrong. That will not solve the hidden entity problem.